# My page doesnt seem to let me do ajax calls to my service files methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I get a error 400, Bad Request.

I have a set of pages that i was trying to write.  (Listing only relevant)

- ./Webpage.aspx
- ./webservices/WebCalls.svc
- ./webservices/IWebCalls.cs
- ./Web.config

and i was looking all over to allow my frontend to communicate with the Webcalls page like follows:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "webservices/WebCalls.svc/DoWork", 
   success: function(){
      console.log(arguments);
   }
});
```

but it doesnt seem to work.

I was thinking to create the files as such:

WebCalls.svc:

```
public class WebCalls: IWebCalls
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "{\"hello\":\"Chop Wood, Carry Water.\"}";
    }
}
```

and IWebCalls.cs:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]

public interface IWebCalls
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "DoWork")]
    string DoWork();
}
```

and in my webConfig, i thought i set it up correctly:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl=""/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MyProj.WebCalls">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="LargeWeb" name="LargeWeb" contract="MyProj.webservices.IWebCalls" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="LargeWeb"
             maxBufferPoolSize="15000000"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="15000000"
             maxBufferSize="15000000">
      <readerQuotas
            maxArrayLength="15000000"
            maxBytesPerRead="15000000"
            maxDepth="32"
            maxNameTableCharCount="15000000"
            maxStringContentLength="15000000"
        />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

When i run it, it just tells me that it has created a service, but when i try to call: **DoWork** it gets a 400 error.

Am I doing something wrong with my approach?  Im just trying to build up a set of pages such that i can query for data.  Originally, i was going to create a GenericHander.asxh for EACH function i wanted to create, but i thought that was too much space.  I knew something like this was an option, but it seems that it doesnt work.

Comment: The error I get is:   400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I also noticed, that despite putting in break points, it does not stop at DoWork, which means it is breaking somewhere else.  My thinking is that the page is recognized, but it doesnt recognize the method, which is why a bad request is being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have decorated the wrong interface `ITestService`. Instead check the declaration of `IWebCalls`.

**EDIT**: Hmm.. I see you updated question ...

I think your services name should probably be `name="MyProj.webservices.WebCalls"` - but assuming that too is a typo, the only issue I see is that `mex` endpoint should not be there. `mex` endpoints are not meant for REST based services.

Comment: This i want to mention was a very annoying and perplexing issue i had to resolve.  I had to watch some examples to FINALLY get it working.  With that said, my resolution was that i needed to create an "AJAX WCF Service" and I have no idea what the difference is between that and a regular WCF Service, design wise.

the name="MyProj.webservices.WdbCalls" i think mightve been the issue.  For some reason when i was working with it, it was giving both WebCalls and IWebCalls a different path.  I noticed they were both as you stated when i created the AJAX WCF Service

Comment: While I can not confirm that your answer was the sole difference between the 2 different file times, I had confirmed that this was indeed a part of the resolution.  I will give the answer to you, but if you can, make a note to look at these comments or to confirm the existance of the file being, in fact, a AJAX WCF Service. :)

Comment: @Fallenreaper: Ajax WCF service is one which uses `webHttpBinding` and has `<webHttp />` endpoint behavior (or `<enableWebScript />` which inherits from `<webHttp />`) enabled on the endpoint. In your case your already had those prerequisites.

Comment: @Fallenreaper: BTW, if you are building a REST based service from scratch, then have a look `ASP.NET Web API` - which is the recommended  API for building .NET RESTful services.